# Select Remote System Type list empty in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, cross-compiling, eclipse-cdt, remote-control

I want to cross compile in Eclipse Luna (Windows -> Linux), but when I want to add a connection in the Remote System view the 
[list is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psyCI.png)

I've installed the newest RSE in Eclipse. Maybe I've missed an important point which I don't know still, and that's why it is empty.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Works fine for me in a new Eclipse Neon install... I didn't install anything special with respect to remote systems.  I get a bunch of types including Clout Doundry, FTP, Linux, Local, SSH, Telnet, Unix and Windows.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue.

You've probably only installed the:

```
Remote System Explorer User Actions
```

1. Go to `Eclipse` -> `Help` -> `Install New Software`
2. Choose the filter as `Photon` (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/photon) or any other version you're using
3. `General Purpose Tools`
4. Install the `Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime`.

**tl;dr**

You must install both:

```
 - Remote System Explorer User Actions 
 - Remote System Explorer End-User Runtime
```

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the below steps

1. Click Help --> AboutEclipse.
2. Click Installation Details.
3. Select all RSE related plugin.
4. Click uninstall.
5. Again Click Help --> Install new software
6. **Select "Oxygen - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen" or your eclipse version url. (Please select this thrusted URL) This is the reason for your issue.**
7. Type Remote in the filters.
8. Select your plugin (RSE) and install freshly.

and your issue will be resolved.